# Query not updating the correct Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to update the fact table with late coming dimension data. See Code below

```
UPDATE FactVehicleStock
SET 
FactVehicleStock.[TOL_BidDateTime] = B.Bid_Date_and_Time,
FactVehicleStock.[TOL_AuctionDate] = B.Date_opened_for_tender,
FactVehicleStock.[TOL_OriginalLoadDate] = B.Original_Load_date,
FactVehicleStock.[TOL_ServiceHistory] = B.Service_History,
FactVehicleStock.[TOL_ReservedPrice] = B.Reserve_price,
FactVehicleStock.[TOL_BidPrice] = B.Bid_Price,
FactVehicleStock.[TOL_OriginalReservedPrice] = B.Original_Reserve_Price,
FactVehicleStock.[TOL_NoOfTimesReloaded] = B.Number_of_times_reloaded
FROM BMR_DWH.dbo.FactVehicleStock as A 
INNER JOIN BMR_STAGE.dbo.STG_Traders_Online as B
ON  A.StockbookNumber = B.Stock_Number 
INNER JOIN BMR_DWH.[dbo].[DimDealership] as C 
ON A.DEALERSHIP_KEY IN (SELECT Distinct [DEALERSHIP_KEY] 
                        FROM BMR_DWH.[dbo].[DimDealership]  
                        INNER JOIN [BMR_STAGE].[dbo].[STG_Traders_Online] E
                        ON LTRIM(RTRIM(C.MOLNUMBER)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(E.MOL_Number))
)
```

Comment: And your question is? What's wrong? What are you expecting? What's the actual output?

Comment: any error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the right UPDATE SELECT Syntaxe.

If you look at the code I did, I had to change a bit your query to do the joins. See if it fits to you.

```
 UPDATE BMR_DWH.dbo.FactVehicleStock as a 
           INNER JOIN BMR_STAGE.dbo.STG_Traders_Online as B
              ON  A.StockbookNumber = B.Stock_Number 
           INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT Distinct [DEALERSHIP_KEY] 
                FROM BMR_DWH.[dbo].[DimDealership] as C 
                 INNER JOIN [BMR_STAGE].[dbo].[STG_Traders_Online] E
                   ON LTRIM(RTRIM(C.MOLNUMBER)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(E.MOL_Number)) ) D
              ON A.DEALERSHIP_KEY = D.DEALERSHIP_KEY
  SET 
       FactVehicleStock.[TOL_BidDateTime] = B.Bid_Date_and_Time,
       FactVehicleStock.[TOL_AuctionDate] = B.Date_opened_for_tender,
       FactVehicleStock.[TOL_OriginalLoadDate] = B.Original_Load_date,
       FactVehicleStock.[TOL_ServiceHistory] = B.Service_History,
       FactVehicleStock.[TOL_ReservedPrice] = B.Reserve_price,
       FactVehicleStock.[TOL_BidPrice] = B.Bid_Price,
       FactVehicleStock.[TOL_OriginalReservedPrice] = B.Original_Reserve_Price,
       FactVehicleStock.[TOL_NoOfTimesReloaded] = B.Number_of_times_reloaded
```

Comment: This answer is not for MSSQL. Written syntax seems like MySql

Comment: [Link to update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(UPDATE_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)